# Fedora 19 fails to start

Tags: linux, boot, fedora, yum

I had updated fedora 17 to fedora 19 (kernel `3.10.11-200`) on my laptop using fedup a ~2-3 weeks back. Everything was fine until yesterday night. All of a sudden while shutting down I got some recurring kernel error message. I couldn't note it down and I powered off the system forcibly. 
The next morning when I started the system the login screen fails to start. I am just able to see kernel messages. I get this message:

`failed to start wait for plymouth boot screen to quit`

When I start terminal with `Ctrl+Alt+F2` i get this message when I log in:

`login: write lastlog failed: No space left on device`

`yum update`doesn't work and fails with this message:

```
error: db5 error(11) from dbenv->open: Resource temporarily unavailable
error: cannot open Packages index using db5 - Resource temporarily unavailable (11)
error: cannot open Packages in /var/lib/rpm
CRITICAL:yum.main:

Error: rpmdb open failed
```

I have around 50 GB for the root partition. Can't understand how can all this space run out. The disk is LVM partitioned. Is there any way to rescue the system without losing files on `/home`.

Comment: Since you have LVM, it should not be so difficult to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my laptop from Fedora 17 to Fedora 19 as well when Fedora 17 went end-of-life.  I too used `fedup` and the process went smoothly.  I like my Fedora 19 system better!

I too use LVM and /home is separate from the root directory.

You could live boot using [SystemRescueCD](http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage) and check to see what's in all your partitions/volumes/etc.  You could also resize them, etc., as well.  If for some reason you can't repair the system, you could move everything you want off the internal drive to an external drive using utilities found on the SystemRescueCD distro.

Comment: i just reinstalled.. no command was working..