# bbswitch fails to turn off discrete graphics

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, fedora-19

Due to some [problems](https://superuser.com/questions/660515/fedora-19-fails-to-start), I had to reinstall fedora. I currently have fedora-19 with kernel version `3.11.4-201`.

I haven't installed NVIDIA drivers and am using the default nouveau drivers for graphics. Bumblebee and bbswitch got installed properly but bbswitch fails to turn off discrete graphics. I did `tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch<<<OFF` but when I check the status it reports it on. 
`dmesg|grep bbswitch` gives this:

```
[   25.192983] bbswitch: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   25.193158] bbswitch: version 0.7
[   25.193165] bbswitch: Found integrated VGA device 0000:00:02.0: \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0
[   25.193172] bbswitch: Found discrete VGA device 0000:01:00.0: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP
[   25.193316] bbswitch: detected an Optimus _DSM function
[   25.193325] bbswitch: Succesfully loaded. Discrete card 0000:01:00.0 is on
[ 1383.773601] bbswitch: device 0000:01:00.0 is in use by driver 'nouveau', refusing OFF
```

Bumblebee-daemon is running but `optirun glxgears -info` gives this:

```
[ 2441.794492] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) Failed to load module "mouse" (module does not exist, 0)

[ 2441.794545] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

At present there is no file called `bbswitch.conf` in `/etc/modprobe.d/` or in `/etc/modules-load.d/`. Is it wise to create a file manually and add `bbswitch load_state=0`to it ?

How do I switch off the discrete graphics card ? It happened quite smoothly in my previous fedora-17 which I *fedupped* to fedora-19. Isn't bumblebeed supposed to turn it off without manual intervention? How do I know if bbswitch is compatible with the kernel?

**EDIT**

During one boot the graphics was turned off but it turned on again when i tried `optirun glxgears -info` (which btw gave the same error). I reinstalled bbswitch and bumblebee but it doesnt solve the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [bbswitch README](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/bbswitch#disable-card-on-boot) is quite clear on this:

> Users of `kmod` should create `/etc/modprobe.d/bbswitch.conf` containing
>   `options bbswitch load_state=0` to set the default options. To load the
>   module, systemd users should create `/etc/modules-load.d/bbswitch.conf`
>   containing `bbswitch`.

In order to allow bbswitch to turn off the video card, you must also prevent the nvidia modules from loading (nouveau in your case). On my system, I have created `/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia.conf` containing:

```
blacklist nvidia
blacklist nouveau
options bbswitch load_state=0
```

Next, initrd should be updated using `dracut --force`

When using Bumblebee, the above is strictly not necessary (the daemon will unload modules and use bbswitch on start-up). Due to race conditions however, it is possible that the bumblebee daemon starts simultaneously while the nouveau driver is being loaded. Therefore it is still wise to blacklist the modules.

Note that when `optirun foo` fails under some conditions, the nvidia card is not disabled. That is why you observe that the nvidia graphics is still enabled.

Comment: i exactly did what you said. just that instead of `nvidia.conf` i made a file called `nouveau.conf`. `dmesg|grep bbswitch` gives the same message: `device 0000:01:00.0 is in use by driver 'nouveau', refusing OFF`

Comment: @bharat_iyengar Following the README, you see that you might have to update your initial ramdisk. I am not so familiar with Fedora, but according to [their wiki](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Common_kernel_problems#How_to_set_module_options_for_boot_drivers), you can run `mkinitrd`. As Fedora seems to use systemd, they likely use kmod too. Usually you do not need to enable the card on shutdown.

Comment: `dracut --force` did the job.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems, same output to reports as your first post.
In answer to your question, to achieve switching, I ended up removing Bumblebee altogether.  Purged it.
Instead I used the ppa installation of the nvidia-340 driver, the latest among proprietary at the moment.
This smoothly managed to blacklist nouveau and handle X server, performed the needed kernel and conf changes.
It has prime and bbswitch as dependencies and it all worked fine from there.
Then run 'sudo prime-select intel' to get intel to work with prime and update latest drivers for it.
When I opened NVIDIA X Server Settings, I was able to switch smoothly
For use of CUDA under Blender I also had to add nvidia-modprobe.
For a more detaileddescription [see this thread](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?411465-CUDA-compute-in-Ubuntu-for-Notebook-with-discrete-Nvidia-GPU&p=3126245#post3126245)