# Bumblebee does not switch off discrete graphics card after all programms shut down

Tags: linux, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

After either `primusrun <any application>` or `optirun <any application>` and then quitting, the discrete nVidia graphics card is still running.

`optirun --status` prints after everything is closed:

```
Bumblebee status: Ready (3.2.1). X inactive. Discrete video card is on.
```

Is there any specific reason for this behavior?

Packages installed include `bumblebee lib32-virtualgl lib32-nvidia-utils lib32-mesa-libgl mesa-demos bbswitch primus lib32-primus`

My distro is Arch (Graphics: Intel HD 4000/ nVidia GT 750M).

`dmesg bbswitch | grep bbswitch` gives:

```
[   14.237164] bbswitch: version 0.8
[   14.237172] bbswitch: Found integrated VGA device 0000:00:02.0: \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0
[   14.237178] bbswitch: Found discrete VGA device 0000:01:00.0: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP
[   14.237266] bbswitch: detected an Optimus _DSM function
[   14.237319] bbswitch: Succesfully loaded. Discrete card 0000:01:00.0 is on
[   14.238942] bbswitch: disabling discrete graphics
[  704.192399] Modules linked in: sha256_ssse3 sha256_generic hmac drbg ansi_cprng ctr ccm bbswitch(O) intel_rapl iosf_mbi x86_pkg_temp_thermal uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops intel_powerclamp videobuf2_core v4l2_common coretemp kvm_intel videodev media kvm sr_mod cdrom hid_generic crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul joydev crc32c_intel mousedev nls_iso8859_1 nls_cp437 vfat fat snd_hda_codec_hdmi aesni_intel arc4 ath3k btusb btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth iTCO_wdt iTCO_vendor_support acer_wmi sparse_keymap rtsx_pci_ms memstick ath9k ath9k_common ath9k_hw aes_x86_64 lrw snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic gf128mul snd_hda_intel r8169 glue_helper mii ath ablk_helper mac80211 snd_hda_codec cryptd pcspkr cfg80211 rfkill i915 evdev input_leds led_class mac_hid drm_kms_helper serio_raw battery
```

Thanks in advance! :)

P.S:
I considered this thread: [bbswitch fails to turn off discrete graphics](https://superuser.com/questions/660624/bbswitch-fails-to-turn-off-discrete-graphics)
Would adding the .conf file help in my case too?

Comment: Here's a temporary workaround: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248853/bumblebee-does-not-switch-off-discrete-graphics-card-after-all-programms-shut-do (just type: `sudo modprobe -r nvidia_modeset && sudo tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch <<< OFF` ). You will have to do this every time you want to switch off your graphics card. So I'd recommend a bash script.