# Bumblebee on Centos 7.2

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, centos, cuda

Trying to install bumblebee on Centos 7.2. My system is an Asus laptop with integrated Intel graphics as well as a Geforce 960M, with no BIOS option for disabling the intel graphics module.

I followed every step in this tutorial (September 2015 version) and installed ElRepo nvidia driver, bumblebee, edited config files etc. as suggested:

https://elrepo.org/tiki/bumblebee

However, now the system freezes at startup. I can only boot the OS at runlevel 3. (The system is a dual boot Win10/Centos)

It seems like bumblebee either fails to start or crashes for some unknown reason. systemctl shows no running bumblebee service, although lsmod shows Nvidia modules running. Calling optirun says bumblebee daemon has either not started or the socket path is incorrect.

Even if I start the bumbleebeed service manually, and then try to go to runlevel 5, the system freezes with no GUI.

Where should I start tracing the issue now?

**EDIT**
Some logs:

**systemctl status bumblebeed.service**:

Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bumblebeed.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: Inactive (dead)

**manually starting bumblebee by invoking bumblebeed -vv**:

[ 1057.431160] [DEBUG]Found card: 01:00.0 (discrete)

[ 1057.431211] [DEBUG]Found card: 00:02.0 (integrated)

[ 1057.431219] [DEBUG]Reading file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf

[ 1057.431605] [INFO]Configured driver: nvidia

[ 1057.431625] [DEBUG]Skipping auto-detection, using configured driver 
'nvidia'

[ 1057.431781] [DEBUG]Process /sbin/modprobe started, PID 2518.

[ 1057.431882] [DEBUG]Hiding stderr for execution of /sbin/modprobe

[ 1057.434369] [DEBUG]SIGCHILD received, but wait failed with No child processes

[ 1057.434484] [DEBUG]bbswitch has been detected.

[ 1057.434493] [INFO]Switching method 'bbswitch' is available and will be used.

[ 1057.434500] [DEBUG]Active configuration:

[ 1057.434505] [DEBUG] bumblebeed config file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf

[ 1057.434511] [DEBUG] X display: :8

[ 1057.434517] [DEBUG] LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib64/nvidia:/usr/lib64/vdpau:
/usr/lib/nvidia:/usr/lib/vdpau

[ 1057.434523] [DEBUG] Socket path: /var/run/bumblebee.socket

[ 1057.434528] [DEBUG] pidfile: /var/run/bumblebeed.pid

[ 1057.434534] [DEBUG] xorg.conf file: /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia

[ 1057.434539] [DEBUG] xorg.conf.d dir: /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d

[ 1057.434545] [DEBUG] ModulePath: /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/extensions/nvidia,/usr/lib64/xorg/modules

[ 1057.434551] [DEBUG] GID name: bumblebee

[ 1057.434556] [DEBUG] Power method: bbswitch

[ 1057.434562] [DEBUG] Stop X on exit: 1

[ 1057.434568] [DEBUG] Driver: nvidia

[ 1057.434574] [DEBUG] Driver module: nvidia

[ 1057.434579] [DEBUG] Card shutdown state: 1

[ 1057.434725] [DEBUG]Process /sbin/modprobe started, PID 2519.

[ 1057.434817] [DEBUG]Hiding stderr for execution of /sbin/modprobe

[ 1057.437091] [DEBUG]SIGCHILD received, but wait failed with No child processes

[ 1057.437127] [DEBUG]Configuration test passed.

[ 1057.437723] [INFO]bumblebeed 3.2.1 started

[ 1057.438288] [INFO]Unloading nvidia driver

[ 1057.438436] [DEBUG]Process rmmod started, PID 2520.

rmmod: ERROR: Module nvidia is in use by: nvidia_modeset

[ 1057.440466] [DEBUG]Process with PID 2520 returned code 1

[ 1060.455840] [ERROR]Unloading nvidia driver timed out.

[ 1060.455927] [DEBUG]Drivers are still loaded, unable to disable card

[ 1060.455935] [INFO]Initialization completed - now handling client requests

**These are running nvidia and i915 kernel modules:**
lsmod|grep nvidia
lsmod|grep i915

nvidia_drm             43405  0

nvidia_modeset        764322  1 nvidia_drm

nvidia              11479193  1 nvidia_modeset

drm_kms_helper        125008  2 i915,nvidia_drm

drm                   349210  4 i915,drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm

i2c_core               40582  8 
drm,i915,i2c_i801,i2c_hid,drm_kms_helper,i2c_algo_bit,nvidia,videodev

i915                 1097338  0

i2c_algo_bit           13413  1 i915

video                  24400  2 i915,asus_wmi

Comment: `lsmod` shows only kernel modules and bumblebee doesn't require it's own kernel module (although it needs `nvidia` and `i915` modules to function). To view state of services explore `systemctl` and `journalctl` commands - eg. to see if bumblebee is even running:  `systemctl status bumblebeed.service` we'd need to see some relevant log entries to know what's going on.

Comment: @MarekRost I edited the question and included some logs at runlevel 3. Please let me know if any other diagnostic is needed.

Comment: It seems that both daemon and manual startup fail for you. From the log it's apparent that `bumblebee` is configured to use `bbswitch` to automatically disable nvidia card until it's needed, but this operation fails to remove the nvidia module from kernel. Looks like your question is in a sense a duplicate of this one: http://superuser.com/questions/660624/bbswitch-fails-to-turn-off-discrete-graphics

Comment: Modifying /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia.conf did not fix the problem. Upon your guidance I came across this bug report which indicates rmmod cannot efficiently disable nvidia driver module, and the code should be replaced with something like modprobe -r : https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/699  Will I be able to compile this for centos, and do you think it may fix it? https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/pull/762/files

Comment: You can try  - i suppose another solution could be to switch to nouveau instead of nvidia driver. It does have decent performance on some cards.

Comment: I compiled Bumblebee-develop from source. Now the aforementioned errors are gone and I can run the daemon from runlevel 3. Again, the system freezes when X is started. Seems like the Nvidia drivers are not compatible with Centos 7 on a double graphics prime hardware setup. Nouveau is installed by default and works, but I can't get to change the screen resolution to anything higher than 600*800 by xrandr with it.